# Node-static example

Tags: node.js, node-static

I've been banging my head against the wall  trying to figure out what's wrong with this code.  I copied it directly from the node-static github repository example, but it doesn't seem to work.  The only modification that I made was to the path of the public files (previously was './public').  In my public folder I have an index.html, but when I hit `http://localhost:8080/index.html` I get nothing.

```
var static = require('node-static');

//
// Create a node-static server instance to serve the './public' folder
//
var file = new(static.Server)('C:\Projects\node\public');

require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        //
        // Serve files!
        //
        file.serve(request, response);
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

If it matters, I'm running Node.js on Windows 7 64 bit.

**Edit:**

I threw in some `console.log` statements and it makes it into the server handler, but not into the listener handler.  Could this have something to do with the 'end' event?

Comment: hmm, though it is solved... But removing addListener is probably not recommended. This piece of code should work well in node v0.8 or earlier. But 'end' event is not fired in node v0.10. Add `.resume()` to the end of handler binding like `request.addListener(...).resume()`. It will force node to fire end event.

Comment: https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I removed the `request.addListener('end', ...)` function:

```
require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {

    //
    // Serve files!
    //
    file.serve(request, response);

}).listen(8080);
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: other solution using express: `app.use(express.static('../client'));`

Comment: can you explain why that solves the problem? What is that line suppose to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a windows path problem. I cannot verify it on my side but I can give you 2 options:

1) escape your backslashes:

```
'C:\\Projects\\node\\public'
```

2) use [path.join](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2)

```
var path = require("path");
var file = new(static.Server)(path.join(__dirname, "public"));
```

`__dirname` is the path of the current file.

Comment: I tried that but to no avail.  I've also edited the original question to include a few more details.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can also serve a error page:

```js
let static = require('node-static');

let fileServer = new static.Server('C:\Projects\node\public');

require('http').createServer(function(request, response) {

  fileServer.serve(request, response, function(exception) {
    if (exception && (exception.status === 404)) {
      fileServer.serveFile('/404.html', 404, {}, request, response);
    }
  });

}).listen(8080);
```

file `404.html` should exist